# Deliver message to consumer and expect response in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a requirement where in (RabbitMQ)server sends the request to the client and client executes the operation and sends the response back to the server.

I would like to know which mechanism to use for this Topic, PubSub, Routing... 
  Can we create the bi-directional connection like server-client similar to xmpp in rabbit mq, if yes how can we do?

thanks
Lokesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Spring AMQP asynchronous consumer with a `MessageListenerAdapter` to invoke a POJO. See the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.3.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/amqp.html#async-consumer).

If you want more control; use a simple `MessageListener` and send the reply with a `RabbitTemplate`.

[This test case](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/test/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/JavaConfigFixedReplyQueueTests.java) shows an end-to-end configuration (client side and server side). The client side automatically takes care of setting the correlationId.

Comment: But from onMessage I will not be able to return the response.  Is there a way to return the response.

Comment: As I said using the `MessageListenerAdapter` your listener can be a POJO `String handleMessage(String input) {...}`; the returned value can be routed to the `replyTo` or with specific routing. Or you can use a `RabbitTemplate` to send the reply.

Comment: If I have sent multiple requests, how can I identify which response is for the request,  is there an inbuilt Latch functionality with RabbitMQ ?

Comment: You would have to set a `correlationId` header.

Comment: Is there an example available for the same. It would be very useful as I am a new bee.

Comment: I added a link to a test case showing both sides (client and server).